# Xcode unable to import framework from filesystem

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, xcode4.6

I'm using Xcode 4.6.3 and I want to include/import several *.a-libraries including headerfiles in my Xcodeproject.
There is a filesystem build like this:

top folder

- includes-several folders with .h header files
- libraries-several folders with .a library files

I tried to set my (User) Header Search Paths in the Build Settings to the location of the includes-folder, but Xcode gave me this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ViewController", referenced from:
    objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What do I do now? Should I copy some files (which ones?) to my project? Do I have to set other settings for my project?